# Devise skip reconfirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-confirmable

I need to skip, not the confirmation email, but REconfirmation emails.

Suppose I have a user with a confirmed email. I want to manually change its email for testing/support purposes

```
u.email # => email1@example.com
u.email = 'email2@example.com'
u.save
u.email # => email1@example.com
u.unconfirmed_email # 'email2@example.com'
```

I tried `u.skip_confirmation!` before and after saving but it doesn't seem to help for reconfirmation emails... the unconfirmed email is not transferred to the email field

Is there any way to force the new unconfirmed email to switch to the normal email ?

Comment: That method only skips sending of mail, that does not confirm the new mail which is stored in `unconfirmed_mail`. maybe you could just confirm the user manually like `u.confirm` . Maybe this is not the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Yes `u.confirm` seems to work, only after I save first though. If you post this an an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method only skips sending of mail, that does not confirm the new mail which is stored in `unconfirmed_mail`. maybe you could just confirm the user manually like `u.confirm`.
`confirm` method works only after object is saved.

To skip reconfirmation email notification use : `skip_confirmation_notification!`

Here is the [Code reference](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L157).

Or try `skip_reconfirmation!` this may confirm new email and avoid sending email notification. I have not used it but I understand so from the comment in code reference above(next method of `skip_confirmation_notification!` defination). so try it and let me know.

Comment: Hey, just realized apparently this does not let me skip the reconfirmation email. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes `skip_reconfirmation!` was definitely the method to use !